# Speeding up data migration in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently doing a data-migration of a very large (at least largest with my newbie experience) database into another structure.

To be factual, I'm attempting the migration of data from a very old heavy modified SMF database into Flarum that I took up as a learning step.

Now I have the SMF specific user IDs for all the users in all the posts, and now I want to migrate the posts to Flarum. The problem however is that SMF user IDs aren't the same as Flarum ones. The ones in the Flarum database are created by  the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute, and hence not the same.

So in order to translate all the posts, I'm using this naive loop which is working, and now am thinking of optimizing it.

```
while ($topic = $topics->fetch())
{
    $posts = $db->query("SELECT * FROM smf_posts WHERE ID_TOPIC = @{$topic->ID_TOPIC}");
    $posts->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    while ($post = $posts->fetch())
    {
        $user = $db2->query("SELECT id FROM flarum_users WHERE user_name = @{$post->posterName}");
        $user = $user->fetch();

        // Now insert the post
    }

    // Now insert the topic into discussions
}
```

Now, having a total of 36,194 topics in the dataset I got, this migration is taking me a whole whopping amount of ~30 minutes on my machine.

I know I had to fetch a lot of data in a single query to make it faster, but I'm just not seeing it how. I initially thought of joining the two tables, but they are in different databases, and even worse in my case, they are in different servers.

How should I be doing this?

Comment: make index of fields `ID_TOPIC` and `user_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I want to comment about whether it's worth optimizing a task you only need to do once. Does it take more than 30 minutes to develop the improvement? If so, then don't bother. Just run it in 30 minutes and call it a success. Unless you need to run this migration many times. Then maybe it's worth improving it.

How many users are there in flarum? Probably not more than a few thousand. You could eliminate the repeated inner queries by doing one query *before* you start processing topics, and hold the username-to-id mapping in a PHP associative array.

```
$userQuery = $db2->query("SELECT id, user_name FROM flarum_users");
$userData = $userQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$userMap = [];
foreach ($userData as $user) {
  $userMap[$user->user_name] = $user->id;
}

// then start processing topics
```

Inside the loop, you can use `$userMap` to change usernames to id's more quickly — just an associate array lookup instead of running another SQL query.

```
while ($post = $posts->fetch())
{
  $userId = $userMap[$post->posterName]; // no SQL query
  // insert post
}
```

Generally, this technique is called [Loop-Invariant Code Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion). If you have code that is run inside a loop, but the result is known to be the same no matter how many times you run it, why do it inside the loop? Do it once, before the loop, and hold the result in some variable.

I also agree with the comment above from @Ben: make sure you have an index on the database table for `smf_posts.ID_TOPIC`, to make it faster to select posts.